# using javascript to get radio button values of multiple forms

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

Note: I am just learning javascript.  So please no jQuery answers yet.  I'll get there.

I have 7 forms, all with groups of radio buttons, that appear one-by-one as one button of each form is clicked.  Works fine.  But by the time I'm done, I may have dozens of forms.  There has to be a better way to get the value of a clicked button that creating a getValue for each form.  Here's what I've done that works:

```
<script>
function initdisplay() {
document.getElementById("painLocation").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("painSystem").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("painTemporPatt").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("painIntensDur").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("painEtiology").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("painKav").style.display="none";
}
window.onload = initdisplay;

var painLocationValue = 0;
var painSystemValue = 0;
var painTemporPattValue = 0;
var painIntesDurValue = 0;
var painEtiologyValue = 0;
var painKavValue = 0;

function getPainLocationValue() {
var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("location");

for (var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
if (radioButtons[i].checked) {
    painLocationValue = radioButtons[i].value;
    document.getElementById("painLocation").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("painSystem").style.display="block";
    alert(painLocationValue);
    }
 }
}

// ... other similar methods here

function getPainKavValue() {
var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("kav");

for (var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
if (radioButtons[i].checked) {
    painKavValue = radioButtons[i].value;
    document.getElementById("painKav").style.display="none";
    alert(radioButtons[i].value);
    }
  }
 } 

</script>

</head>
```

Then the HTML looks like this:

```
<body>
<form id="painLocation" action="">
<p class="formPainCode">Q1: What is the location of your ailment?</p>
<input type="radio" name="location" value="000" onclick="getPainLocationValue()"> Head, Face, Mouth<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="location" value="100" onclick="getPainLocationValue()"> Cervical   (neck) Region<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="location" value="200" onclick="getPainLocationValue()"> Upper Shoulder and Upper Limbs<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="location" value="300" onclick="getPainLocationValue()"> Thoracic (chest) Region<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="location" value="400" onclick="getPainLocationValue()"> Abdominal Region<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="location" value="500" onclick="getPainLocationValue()"> Lower Back, Lumbar Spine, Sacrum, Coccyx<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="location" value="600" onclick="getPainLocationValue()"> Lower Limbs<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="location" value="700" onclick="getPainLocationValue()"> Pelvic Region<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="location" value="800" onclick="getPainLocationValue()"> Anal, Perineal, Genital Region<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="location" value="900" onclick="getPainLocationValue()"> More than one location<br><br>
</form>
...
<form id="painKav" action="">
<p class="formPainCode">Q11: On which side of your body is your ailment?</p>
<input type="radio" name="kav" value="R" onclick="getPainKavValue()"> Right<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="kav" value="L" onclick="getPainKavValue()"> Left<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="kav" value="C" onclick="getPainKavValue()"> Center<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="kav" value="M" onclick="getPainKavValue()"> More than one side<br><br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to learn about event delegation. Create a listener on an ancestor element (say on the body or enclosing div element) and use *event.target* (or event.srcElement in older IE) to get the element that fired the event. You can then test properties of the element to see if it's one that you're interested in and go from there. You might like to check out the form functions at [JavaScript Toolbox](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/form/).

Comment: Above comment is good advice. You may also consider abstracting your methods with classes (prototypes) or static methods which do not address specific IDs or anything and then hook onto the form onSubmit attribute to call them.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent advice.  I also need to forget about my "no jQuery" condition.

Answer (score 0):

After another couple of frustrating hours, I dropped my "no jQuery" condition.  The rest was simple.  I used the following code to detect a click, and get the value of the button clicked.  And since I expected some of my forms to include input types other than radio buttons, I changed that as well.  At this point, the jQuery looks like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").click(function() {
    var painCode = $(this).val();
    alert("The painCode for this person is " + painCode);   
    });//end click function
}); //end document ready    
</script>
```

I cleaned up the html.  A typical form now looks like this:

```
<div id="painIntensDur">
<form class="painCodeForm" action="">
<p class="formPainCode">Q4: If you experience pain from your ailment, which of the following best describes its intensity and duration? </p>
<input type="radio" name="intensdur" value=".1" > Mild and less than 1 month<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="intensdur" value=".8" > Mild and 1 to 6 months<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="intensdur" value=".9" > Mild and more than 6 months<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="intensdur" value=".4" > Medium and  less than 1 month<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="intensdur" value=".2" > Medium and 1 to 6 months<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="intensdur" value=".3" > Medium and more than 6 months<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="intensdur" value=".7" > Severe and  less than 1 month<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="intensdur" value=".5" > Severe and 1 to 6 months<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="intensdur" value=".6" > Severe and more than 6 months<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="intensdur" value=".0" > Not sure<br><br>
</form>
</div>
```

Thanks again to the excellent advice.  I'm sure it will come in handy later.